# Making a ggplot bar plot with proportion labels with position = "dodge"

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data set:

```
    structure(list(X = 1:6, lake = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "z"
), harv = c(27351.4588, 83303.21336, 32258.14338, 64784.5816, 
107123.759, 85215.79412), prop2 = c(24.7, 75.3, 33.2, 66.8, 55.7, 
44.3), variable = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("User", 
"Non-User"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make a plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=lake,y=harv))+
geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat="identity",position = position_dodge2(width=0.9))+  
geom_text(size=7,aes(x=lake, y=harv, label = paste0(round(prop2,digits = 2),"%"),
vjust=-0.5), position = position_dodge2(width=0.9))
```

[image]

why are my proportion labels going to the wrong column? It works when variable isn't a factor but I want bars to remain in the order I set for the factor.

Comment: The issue is the grouping. Add `group=variable` as an aesthetic to geom_text. Or move `fill=variable` to `ggplot()` to make it a global aes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `geom_col()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=lake,y=harv, fill=variable))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width=0.9))+
  geom_text(size=7,aes(x=lake, y=harv, label = paste0(round(prop2,digits = 2),"%"),
                       vjust=-0.5), position = position_dodge2(width=0.9))
```

[image]